# How do I implement this app despite its limitations?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, powerschool

Goal:

Hall monitors at a large school can scan student ID and easily enter tardy information in PowerSchool.

Limitations:

-I get no access to PowerSchool due to legal limitations

-Can't pass ID as a parameter into the URL because database ID differs from student ID. I could get a list, but with the acquisition of new students and everything, this would be hard to maintain.

My idea:

Create an app that scans the barcode, copies the student ID to the clipboard, immediately opens up a WebView to have the user sign in, and they can tap and hold to paste the ID into the user lookup field.

However, this is highly inefficient and a last resort. Is there any way to improve this given the extreme limitations I have?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling in a barcode is fairly simple.  I think you're probably on the right track with opening a webview, but depending on the URL structure, you may even be able to modify the html body to automatically input the scanned barcode into the necessary field.

3 options I can think of:

1)  The webpage you're loading, does it recall the previously used login from a cookie?  If it uses one to auto populate the field, modify the saved cookie before loading the webview.

2)  If a cookie isn't used, see if you can populate the form once the page has finished loading

3)  This is the most ambitious.  If you know the structure used for the form, and don't need the student to enter a password, send the form data instead of opening the login page.  Here's an example of manually populating and sending a form using Paypal:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mobile.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"]];

NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cmd=_xclick&business=paypal@example.com&image_url=https://example.com/logo.jpg&no_shipping=2&no_note=1&amount=%1.2f&currency_code=USD&notify_url=https://example.com/paypalipn.cfm&return=http://example.com/", [self.orderAmount floatValue]];

  [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  self.webView.delegate = self;
  [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Of course, that means you'll have to dissect the sign in page and pull the form URL and data format, but that should help make it much easier on the hall monitors in the end.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks so much! I'd like to do a student lookup with the copied barcode, however, the barcode id is different from the "database" id, and as another limitation: I don't have access to the database ids :(

Comment: But your idea is to use the barcode to copy/paste into the text form on the web page (I'm assuming the barcode contains the student ID). That's exactly what this will accomplish. All you're doing, is pulling in the barcode, then doing the same POST call that the web page will do.

Comment: oh now I understand! Thanks! Any way to capture post data to track how data is being sent?

Comment: That's just a basic web page, isn't it?  It should be fairly easy to dissect the HTML code and determine what's being sent in the body.  I suppose you can use the Safari web inspector to see the data, but I'm not a strong enough of a web programmer to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Without actually having access to the database that you want to use and with the difference of IDs it would seem there is no other way apart from what you suggest with the barcode scanner and copying it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Your app should be able to emulate what the user does in the browser. You may need to capture the web requests from your phone and the responses sent from the PowerSchool server to analyze exactly what's happening during login, search, and report.

Admittedly, this would be a very "brittle" solution, subject to issues caused by unexpected changes to the server.